# UIWebView не показывает изменения, сделанные с помощью javascript

Tags: objective-c

Здравствуйте.
При показе страницы в UIWebView требуется выделять участки текста. Для этого используется метод stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString и javascript, который вставляет нужный контекст в теги "span" с требуемым стилем и в итоге меняет document.body.innerHTML. Однако встречается ситуация, когда document.body.innerHTML меняется нужным образом, и это видно на выходе stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, а компонент WebView эти изменения не показывает. Как с этим бороться?

```
    js = @"\
    body_inner_html = document.body.innerHTML;\
    var __search = '%@';\
    var __a;\
    var __re;\
    var i,k;\
    __re = new RegExp('('+__search+')','gi');\
    __a = document.getElementsByTagName('*');\
    for (i = 0; i < __a.length; i++) {\
    for (k=0; k<__a[i].childNodes.length; k++) {\
    if (__a[i].childNodes[k].nodeType == 3) {\
    __a[i].childNodes[k].textContent = __a[i].childNodes[k].textContent.replace(__re,'searchres$1');\
    }\
    }\
    }\
    var __s;\
    __re = new RegExp('(searchres'+__search+')','gi');\
    __s = document.body.innerHTML.replace(__re,'<span style=\"background-color:#e0e0e0;\">$1</span>');\
    __re = new RegExp('searchres','g');\
    __s = __s.replace(__re,'');\
    document.body.innerHTML = __s;\
    ";
    expr = [NSString stringWithFormat:js,search_context_value];
    [webview1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:expr];
```

Comment: код покажете???

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko, добавил код.